# How to - Loop through a String and identify a specific character and add to the string

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, substring, indexof

I'm currently trying to loop through a `String` and identity a specific character within that string then add a specific character following on from the originally identified character.

**For example** using the **string: aaaabbbcbbcbb**
And the character I want to identify being: **c**

So every time a c is detected a following c will be added to the string and the loop will continue.

Thus **aaaabbbcbbcbb** will become **aaaabbbccbbccbb**.

I've been trying to make use of `indexOf()`,`substring` and `charAt()` but I'm currently either overriding other characters with a c or only detecting one c.

Comment: Kindly share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you've asked for a loop, but won't something as simple as a replace suffice?

```
String inputString = "aaaabbbcbbcbb";
String charToDouble = "c";

String result = inputString.replace(charToDouble, charToDouble+charToDouble);
// or `charToDouble+charToDouble` could be `charToDouble.repeat(2)` in JDK 11+
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##lY49D4IwEIZ3fsWFqY1KIitxc3XSzTgcpdFioaQ9SIzht2NBSGqMg02TfrzPPXcldrgpi/swCI3OwQFV/YwAmjbXSoAjJH90RhVQ@Ygdyar6er4A8hEDeH@AqpuW5vsOYvQrz3Mx7TgLSXFDezJ74xvIERU@DnMrXatp66PAmVjZaBSShdXrD9cqfPDsW5n@rRwRicRSzpcZH45klZiWksZLSNdsnnfp@AtIJ6CP@mF4AQ)

If you insist on using a loop however:

```
String inputString = "aaaabbbcbbcbb";
char charToDouble = 'c';

String result = "";
for(char c : inputString.toCharArray()){
  result += c;
  if(c == charToDouble){
    result += c;
  }
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##bU7NDoIwDL7zFA0XRow8gISD0asnvBkPZYAOByNbISGGZ8fxo2Jis7TL1@@nBba4LdLHMHCJxsAJRfV0AOomkYKDISQ7WiVSKO2KxaRFdbtcAf2RBjADIKq6oeUfgYu2kiTh03PDicnvqKd2Vkdl7TNL9Lg3L9deOjONpNFmUeZKs1kNu3VSQOpg4b3W2DF/OQje@k0EPFwgkTMOUfQT/@H/VfTOt8edoawMVENBbXNJVmxW@CO7d/pheAE)

Comment: A much more simple solution! I had never come across .replace() thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all the characters. Add each one to a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). If it matches the character you're looking for then add it again.

```
final String test = "aaaabbbcbbcbb";
final char searchChar = 'c';

final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (final char c : test.toCharArray())
{
    builder.append(c);
    if (c == searchChar)
    {
        builder.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Output

> aaaabbbccbbccbb

Answer (score 1):

You probably are trying to modify a String in java. Strings in Java are `immutable` and cannot be changed like one might do in `c++`.

You can use StringBuilder to insert characters. eg:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("acb");
builder.insert(1, 'c');
```

Comment: This just adds a 'c' between the 1st and 2nd characters. That's not what they asked for.

Comment: Inserting an extra `c` when you find a `c` could be one approach to solve his problem. @Michael

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer suggesting `String.replace` is the best solution, but if you need to do it some other way (e.g. for an exercise), then here's a 'modern' solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String inputString = "aaaabbbcbbcbb";
    final int charToDouble = 'c';  // A Unicode codepoint
    final String result = inputString.codePoints()
            .flatMap(c -> c == charToDouble ? IntStream.of(c, c) : IntStream.of(c))
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
    assert result.equals("aaaabbbccbbccbb");
}
```

This looks at each character in turn (in an IntStream). It doubles the character if it matches the target. It then accumulates each character in a StringBuilder.

A micro-optimization can be made to pre-allocate the StringBuilder's capacity. We know the maximum possible size of the new string is double the old string, so `StringBuilder::new` can be replaced by `() -> new StringBuilder(inputString.length()*2)`. However, I'm not sure if it's worth the sacrifice in readability.